# How can i return the response of this function?

Tags: java, android

I have this public method with a return value of String, but i cant return anything on result as it is givving me the error that i cant return. I need to get the response from the method back to the class that called this method, please help.

I have tried getters and setters, none helps and just gives me more errors.

```
public String callGraphAPI(String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting volley request to graph");

    /* Make sure we have a token to send to graph */
    if (mAuthResult.getAccessToken() == null) {return "not signed in";}

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();

    try {
        parameters.put("key", "value");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to put parameters: " + e.toString());
    }
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            parameters,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            /* Successfully called graph, process data and send to UI */
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                return "Hello";
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//this is where i want to return the resutl
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + mAuthResult.getAccessToken());
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

The error is cannot return from a void method. which i understand but how do i get the response back then? how can i get it out of that method?

Comment: This is unclear.  What result do you want to return?  Are you saying you don't want to return anything at that point? If so, just return `null` and make sure the calling code can deal with a `null` return.  If not, please explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to return the response from onResponse Method, But it is insde that void method. So is there like a super return, i dont know. All i need is that response back.

Comment: Where do you call "callGraphAPI()" method? can you post it aswell?

Comment: You haven't shown all the relevant code.  You instantiated the request but where did you add it to the request queue?  The request runs asynchronously, on a completely different thread.  Where do you wait for the request to complete?

Comment: I just call it using Stri

Comment: String result = CallGraphAPI(url)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use callback.

```
public interface Callback {

    void onResult(String result);

}
```

Change your code something like this:

```
public String callGraphAPI(String url, Callback callback) {
    ...
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            parameters,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            /* Successfully called graph, process data and send to UI */
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

            //your result
            callback.onResult(response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + mAuthResult.getAccessToken());
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Okay, how do i then get that response?

Comment: You need to create an instance of the callback while calling `callGraphAPI`. Please post the code where you call this method

Comment: callGraphAPI(MSGRAPH_URL);

Comment: You call asynchronous method using Volley JsonObjectRequest, there is no way to call it synchronously. Using callback you can "subscribe" to result and react when your response is ready